# How to make 2 (or more) custom post type post pages sit under the same slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I've created 2 `custom post types` like so:

```
register_post_type(
    'resources',
    theme_build_post_args(
        // $slug, $singular, $plural
        'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
        array(
            'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'public'        => true,
            'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
            // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources' ),
        )
    )
);

register_post_type(
  'video-demos-tours',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'video-demos-tours', 'Video Demos & Tours', 'Video Demos & Tours',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
      'menu_position' => 23,
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'public'          => true,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
      // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources'),
    )
  )
);
```

`video-demo-tours` shares the same `single-` template as the `resources` post type, via this function:

```
function custom_single_template($single_template) {
  global $post;
  if (in_array($post->post_type, array('video-demos-tours'))) {
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-resources.php';
  }
  return $single_template;
}

add_filter('single_template', 'custom_single_template');
```

All posts from `resources` and `video-demos-tours` are being shown on `/resources`

But, when I click into a `video-demos-tours` post, the URL is `/video-demos-tours/post-name`. I want it to be `/resources/post-name`.

To do this, I've tried `rewrite`:

```
function custom_post_type_permalink($url, $post) {
    if (in_array($post->post_type, array('resources', 'video-demos-tours'))) {
        return home_url("resources/{$post->post_type}/{$post->post_name}/");
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_permalink', 10, 2);
```

But, it didn't change anything (have flushed permalinks after too).

Any ideas?

### Edit

Latest `CTP` and function:

```
register_post_type(
  'resources',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'public'          => true,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
    )
  )
);

register_post_type(
  'video-demos-tours',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'video-demos-tours', 'Video Demos & Tours', 'Video Demos & Tours',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
      'menu_position' => 23,
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'public'          => true,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources' )
    )
  )
);

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse418900_parse_request' );

function wpse418900_parse_request( $wp ) {
  $post_types = array( 'resources', 'video-demos-tours' );
  if ( preg_match( '#^resources/#', $wp->request ) &&
    isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'] ) &&
    in_array( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $post_types )
  ) {
    $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = $post_types;
  }
}
```

I have flushed permalinks via settings but my posts still sit under `/video-demos-tours/video-post/`

To clarify (incase misunderstood), I want my video posts to sit under the resources CPT slug, as in `/resources/video-post/`.

### Edit 2 ##:

Full list of CPTs and taxonomies:

```
public function post_types_taxonomies() {

  register_post_type(
    'resources',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'blogs-and-news',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'blogs-and-news', 'Blogs and News', 'Blogs and News',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 21,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/blogs-and-news'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'case-studies',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'case-studies', 'Case study', 'Case studies',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 22,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'case-studies', 'with_front' => false),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'video-demos-tours',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'video-demos-tours', 'Video Demos & Tours', 'Video Demos & Tours',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 23,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources/video-demos-tours' )
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'whitepapers',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'whitepapers-and-reports', 'Whitepaper & Reports', 'Whitepapers & Reports',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => null,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/whitepapers-and-reports'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'solution-briefs',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'solution-briefs', 'Solution brief', 'Solution briefs',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 25,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/solution-briefs'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'user-guides',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'user-guides', 'User guide', 'User guides',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 26,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/user-guides'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'product-briefs',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'product-briefs', 'Product brief', 'Product briefs',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 27,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/product-briefs'),
      )
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'webinars-whiteboards',
    theme_build_post_args(
      // $slug, $singular, $plural
      'webinars-whiteboards', 'Webinars & Whiteboards', 'Webinars & Whiteboards',
      array(
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
        'menu_position' => 28,
        'has_archive'   => false,
        'public'        => true,
        'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
        'taxonomies'        => array('tags'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources/webinars-whiteboards'),
      )
    )
  );

}


function themes_taxonomy() {

  $post_types = array('resources', 'blogs-and-news', 'case-studies', 'video-demos-tours', 'whitepapers', 'solution-briefs', 'user-guides', 'product-briefs', 'webinars-whiteboards');

  $taxonomy_args = array(
      'hierarchical'       => true,
      'public'             => true,
      'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'resources/tag'),
      'label'              => 'Tags',
      'query_var'          => true,
      'show_admin_column'  => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
  );

  foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
    register_taxonomy(
      'tags', // taxonomy name/slug
      $post_type, // attach to this post type
      $taxonomy_args
    );
  }

}
```

`theme_build_post_args()`:

```
public function buildPostLabels( $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts' )
{
    if($singular != 'Post' && $plural == 'Posts' ) {
        $plural = $singular . 's';
    }


    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x($plural, 'post type general name', 'lightbox'),
        'singular_name'      => _x($singular, 'post type singular name', 'lightbox'),
        'menu_name'          => _x($plural, 'admin menu', 'lightbox'),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x($singular, 'add new on admin bar', 'lightbox'),
        'add_new'            => _x('Add New', $singular, 'lightbox'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Add New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
        'new_item'           => __('New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Edit ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
        'view_item'          => __('View ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
        'all_items'          => __('All ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
        'search_items'       => __('Search ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __('Parent ' . $plural . ':', 'lightbox'),
        'not_found'          => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found.', 'lightbox'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found in Trash.', 'lightbox'),
    );


    return $labels;
}

public function buildPostArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
{
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->postDefaults);

    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

    $args['labels'] = $this->buildPostLabels($singular, $plural);

    return $args;
}

function theme_build_post_args( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
{
    $builder = new theme_PTTaxArgBuilder;
    return $builder->buildPostArgs($slug, $singular, $plural, $args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting `/video-demos-tours/post-name` instead of `/resources/post-name` because the following line in your `theme_build_post_args` function is setting the rewrite slug to the post type slug (`video-demos-tours`):

```php
$args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;
```

So you should fix that, but as for how, that is up to you.

---

But then, although fixing that would give you the permalink structure you preferred (e.g. `https://example.com/resources/video-post/`), visiting the URL of a post in the *other* CPT (`resources`) would display a 404 error because the rewrite rules for `video-demos-tours` now have a higher priority than the ones for the `resources` CPT.

Therefore, you should actually use a different/unique rewrite slug which is not already in use by another post type.

- `resources/video-demos-tours` can be used, but the post type must be registered *before* the `resources` CPT.

If, however, you must share the same rewrite slug between two or more of your CPTs, then one easy way without having to add custom rewrite rules, is by using the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) like so:

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse418900_parse_request' );
function wpse418900_parse_request( $wp ) {
    // Define the post types which share the same rewrite slug.
    $post_types = array( 'resources', 'video-demos-tours' );

    // If the URL path (i.e. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) begins with /resources/
    // as in https://example.com/resources/video-post/, then we'd modify the
    // post_type value so that WordPress will "choose" from one of the above
    // post types.
    if ( preg_match( '#^resources/#', $wp->request ) &&
        isset( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $wp->query_vars['name'] ) &&
        in_array( $wp->query_vars['post_type'], $post_types )
    ) {
        $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = $post_types;
    }
}
```

It worked well for me on my WordPress v6.3.1 site, but:

1. Remember that the solution will result in a slight overhead when loading the single post page.
2. The same slug (`post_name`) can be shared among posts in different post types, however, you would want to always use a unique slug with your posts if the post type is sharing the same rewrite slug.

Comment: PS: Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules, i.e. re-save your permalinks, and before doing so, you should remove the `add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_permalink', 10, 2);` from your code.

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for the insight. I've tried adjusting my code to follow your above approach, but it still yields the same approach. I've edited my question to showcase the CPT declaration and the rewrite. I've also tried `'with_front' => false`. Just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: Do you have any taxonomies, and/or other CPTs other than the two in question, where the rewrite base/slug is exactly `resources` or that it begins with a `resources/`? Have you already tried deactivating all plugins (for a while) and did the same issue persist? You should also now add to your question the code for the `theme_build_post_args` function.

Comment: I have 9 `CPT`s in total and 1 custom taxonomy. None which are exactly `resources`, but they do being with `resources/`. I've updated my question to showcase all the CPTs, taxonomies and also `theme_build_post_args`. Have also tried it with plugins disabled and flushing permalinks after.

Comment: Hi Sally, following up on the above, the issue is definitely in `theme_build_post_args` or a related function as when I created the `CPT` without `theme_build_post_args` and added the `rewrite` and `parse request` as you've mentioned in your answer, it started to work. Apologies for not seeing so sooner and thanks me helping me identify it!

Comment: "*the issue is definitely in `theme_build_post_args`*" - *yes*, and I have revised my answer, so you should check it out. But the `parse_request` code remains the same (I only added some comments).